# Segfault from tiny assembly file

Tags: assembly

The following tiny assembly file generates an executable that segfaults:

```
.globl _start
_start:
        ret
```

What is wrong?

Edit: x86-64 Fedora 20 Linux, GNU userland

Comment: Whereto should the program return with `ret`?

Comment: Need more info re: OS, architecture, etc.  In DOS, ret was valid as it would return to an exit error level 0 interrupt call in the PSP.  Other platforms a simple ret may not be legal.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch this is the correct answer. Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DOS, ret was valid as it would return to an exit error level 0 interrupt call in the PSP. Other platforms a simple ret may not be legal.

Answer (score 1):

The program is trying to go to a bogus return address -> segfault.